# Error CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.DateTime' to 'int' (CS0029) (DeclaringConstructor)

Tags: c#

Whats wrong here, its code from book but not working?

```cs
using System;

namespace DeclaringConstructor
{
    public class Time
    {
        int Year;
        int Month;
        int Date;
        int Hour;
        int Minute;
        int Second;

        public void DisplayCurrentTime()
        {
            System.Console.WriteLine("{0}/{1}/{2}/{3}/{4}/{5}", Month, Date, Year, Hour, Minute, Second);
        }

        //konstruktor
        public Time(System.DateTime dt)
        {
            Year = dt.Year;
            Month = dt.Month;
            Date = dt.Date;
            Hour = dt.Hour;
            Minute = dt.Minute;
            Second = dt.Second;

        }
    }
    public class Tester
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            System.DateTime currentTime = System.DateTime.Now;
            Time t = new Time(currentTime);
            t.DisplayCurrentTime();

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `dt.Date` return a date time. You perhaps mean `.Day`, if it's code from a book I believe it's a typo. When trusting auto completion to mutch

Comment: @xdtTransform, do you mean "two March"?

Comment: @Sinatr, Well "Much" is `/mʌtʃ/`for some reason that `/t/` get hardcoded into the word to enforce that prononciation. For the missing O in "too", I had to take that extra lettre in "much" from somewhere.. It doesn't grow on tree.

Answer (score 0):

the problem is here:

```
 Date = dt.Date;
```

you need the `Day` property of `Datetime`. Try like:

```
Day = dt.Day;
```